# Asynchronous Thread Lifetime & WPF UI Update

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

On button click I have fired call to `StartContinuousThread` which keeps polling the server every one second.

```
public class ThreadsWindow
{
    CancellationTokenSource wtoken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private void btnStartTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartContinuousThread();
    } 

    void StartContinuousThread()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            var fact = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                CallServer();
                Task.Delay(1000, wtoken.Token);
            },
            wtoken.Token);
        }
     }
}
```

`StartContinuousThread` starts executing, but `btnStartTest_Click event handler` finishes its execution.

> How `StartContinuousThread method` would be able to update UI in this
>   case?
>
> I wonder whether `StartContinuousThread` is also terminated with event handler, since there is no wait keyword for re-joining.

Please help!

Comment: There are several problems with that code.. what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to update the UI thread after `CallServer` returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you goal is to poll the server every second you have a number of problem.

1. There is no loop.  You execute the method once and then stop.
2. You create a task using `Delay` and then ignore it.  You ought to be creating a continuation of that task to do the rest of the work to actually not do anything for a second.

Here is an implementation that addresses those issues:

```
private async Task StartContinuousThread(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await Task.Run(() => CallServer());
        await Task.Delay(1000, token);
    }
}
```

Another possibility, especially if you're using an older version of C#, would be to use a timer to run some code every second.

As for updating the UI; you can do so freely anywhere outside of the call to `Task.Run` in this example.  In your example you'd need to use some mechanism to marshal back to the UI thread, such as capturing the UI's synchronization context and posting to it.

Comment: thanks, Would you explain a bit please about Marshalling back to UI thread. btb I missed while loop while posting here.

Comment: @lakshyaleader It's a widely discussed topic that you can easily research if you would like to know more.